# Odd behavior of switch and tildes in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to assign a value using the `switch` function in R Shiny and I am having an odd problem with the tildes. In the code below, if I select "BAYAMÓN" in the UI, the switch function on the server assigns NULL to x, when it should be 5. On the other hand, if I use an `if...else` structure, it works (first set of commented lines). If I set the value of a variable to "BAYAMÓN" and use `switch`, that also works (second set of commented lines). I am using the latest version of Shiny. Thank you.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

choices_Region <- c("ARECIBO" = "ARECIBO", "BAYAMÓN" = "BAYAMÓN", "CAGUAS" = "CAGUAS")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel(h3("Test"), windowTitle = "Test"),
   sidebarLayout (
       sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("select_Region", label = "Región", choices = choices_Region)
       ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Debug", verbatimTextOutput("debug"))
            )
        )
)))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$debug <- renderPrint({
    x <- switch(input$select_Region, "ARECIBO" = 4, "BAYAMÓN" = 5, "CAGUAS" = 6)
    x # prints NULL if BAYAMÓN selected

    # region <- input$select_Region
    # x <- if (region == "ARECIBO") 4 
         # else if (region == "BAYAMÓN") 5
         # else 6
    # x # prints 5 if BAYAMÓN selected in ui

    # region <- "BAYAMÓN"
    # x <- switch(region, "ARECIBO" = 4, "BAYAMÓN" = 5, "CAGUAS" = 6)
    # x # prints 5

    })
})
```